# NSMutableArray not storing elements

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to record an audio, and save the path of each recorded audio in the array. i'm using this code to save the audio:

```
 (IBAction)AudioRecord:(id)sender {
[self.AudioRecorder record];

NSURL *audioFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"audioRecording.m4a"]];
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileURL error:nil];

NSUserDefaults *audioDefaults= [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[audioDefaults setURL:audioFileURL forKey:@"saveAudio"];
[audioDefaults synchronize];

NSUserDefaults *defaultsAudio=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSUserDefaults *defaultsForArrayA =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *AudioArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
AudioArray =[defaultsForArrayA arrayForKey:@"myAudio"];
NSString *Audiopath=[audioFileURL path];
[AudioArray addObject:Audiopath];
defaultsAudio=defaultsForArrayA;
[defaultsAudio setObject:AudioArray forKey:@"myAudio"];
[defaultsAudio synchronize];



if (AudioArray.count==0)

    _check.text=@"nothing";
else
    _check.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)AudioArray.count];
```

I'm using the if statement just to check if the objects are being saved in the array. But it turns out nothing is being saved !

when I remove this line:

```
AudioArray =[defaultsForArrayA arrayForKey:@"myAudio"];
```

the array works. But I need this line.

Comment: First off, name variables starting with a lower-case letter.  Second, when you do `defaultsAudio=defaultsForArrayA;`, you overwrite the values you fetched with `defaultsAudio=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`.  Third, when you do `AudioArray =[defaultsForArrayA arrayForKey:@"myAudio"];` you overwrite the value you set with `AudioArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`.

Comment: Check if AudioArray is nil (nil.count will == 0 too).   My guess is that `[defaultsAudio setObject:AudioArray forKey:@"myAudio"];` is returning nil, instead of a populated or blank NSMutableArray.

Comment: @ansible ooh yes it is nil!

Comment: @ansible but how come it works when I remove this line : `AudioArray =[defaultsForArrayA arrayForKey:@"myAudio"];` ?

Comment: Learn how to use NSLog, and the debug commands in the console window, so you can examine the values at each step along the way, rather than getting to the end and wondering what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change these lines:

```
NSMutableArray *AudioArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
AudioArray =[defaultsForArrayA arrayForKey:@"myAudio"];
```

to

```
AudioArray =[[defaultsForArrayA arrayForKey:@"myAudio"] mutableCopy];
if (!AudioArray) {
    AudioArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

Currently, you are trying to add objects to a non-mutable NSArray.  Note that in these lines:

```
NSMutableArray *AudioArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
AudioArray =[defaultsForArrayA arrayForKey:@"myAudio"];
```

You are first assigning an empty NSMutableArray to `AudioArray`.  Then you are assigning it a different value in the second line, and overwriting the first value with an NSArray.

Comment: @JoshCaswell is correct here in that the array returned from defaultsForArrayA is likely returning nil, hence no exception being thrown.  But my answer still stands as another problem you will face with your code.

Comment: @user3191725 I have updated my answer to something that should fix both problems for you

Answer (score -1):

The problem is `[defaultsAudio setObject:AudioArray forKey:@"myAudio"];` is setting AudioArray to nil. So it will silently ignore any calls to it including adding new items.  And AudioArray.count == 0 when nil.

The reason it works without this call is because you are initializing it right above `NSMutableArray *AudioArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` which will return an empty `NSMutableArray` which you can add objects to.

One solution (if you can't modify setObject: forKey:) is to use a temp array and merge it into AudioArray.

```
NSMutableArray *temp;
temp =[defaultsForArrayA arrayForKey:@"myAudio"];
AudioArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:temp];
```

So it will work if it returns nil, a blank array, or a populated array.